# With Akka Streams, how do I know when a source has completed?

Tags: elasticsearch, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams, alpakka

I have an Alpakka Elasticsearch `Sink` that I'm keeping around between requests. When I get a request, I create a `Source` from an HTTP request and turn that into a `Source` of Elasticsearch `WriteMessage`s, then run that with `mySource.runWith(theElasticseachSink)`.

1. How do I get notified when the source has completed? Nothing useful seems to be materialized.
2. Will completion of the source be passed to the sink, meaning I have to create a new one each time?
3. If yes to the above, would decoupling them somehow with `Flow.fromSourceAndSink` help?

My goal is to know when the HTTP download has completed (including the `via`s it goes through) and to be able to reuse the sink.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass around the single parts of a flow as you wish, you can even pass around the whole executabe graph (those are immutables). The run() call materializes the flow, but does not change your graph or its parts.

1) 
Since you want to know when the HttpDownload passed the flow , why not use the full graphs Future[Done] ? Assuming your call to elasticsearch is asynchronous, this should be equal since your sink just fires the call and does not wait.
You could also use Source.queue (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source/queue.html) and just add your messages to the queue, which then reuses the defined graph so you can add new messages when proocessing is needed. This one also materializes a SourceQueueWithComplete allowing you to stop the stream.
Apart from this, reuse the sink wherever needed without needing to wait for another stream using it.

2) As described above: no, you do not need to instantiate a sink multiple times.

Best Regards,
Andi

Comment: How do I actually get a `Future[Done]`, though? Akka-http's `ResponseEntity`'s `dataBytes` source materializes `Any` (`def dataBytes: Source[ByteString, Any]`), and I've no idea why or what that's supposed to be.

Comment: Well, there I was referring to the materialized value of the sink. From what you describe, you really need it at the Source  ? For the sink you could use Sink.foreach , which materializes a Future[Done] . Please try to specify why exactly there is the need for this on the source in case you need it there.

Comment: If you really need it, you could add a viaMat and write custom materialization for your source which provides the status and then pass it down the stream via (Keep.right) or (Keep.left). Tonight I wont have time to compose an example, but in case you need it, please post some example (simplified) code.

Comment: I put up a small repro here: https://github.com/danellis/akka-es-test. As you can see, I get a `NotUsed` when I run it, so I have nothing to work with there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Alpakka's Elasticsearch library also supports flow shapes, so I can have my source go via that and run it via any sink that materializes a future. `Sink.foreach` works fine here for testing purposes, for example, as in https://github.com/danellis/akka-es-test.

```
Flow fromFunction { product: Product =>
    WriteMessage.createUpsertMessage(product.id, product.attributes)
} via ElasticsearchFlow.create[Map[String, String]](index, "_doc")
```

to define `es.flow` and then

```
val graph = response.entity.withSizeLimit(MaxFeedSize).dataBytes
    .via(scanner)
    .via(CsvToMap.toMap(Utf8))
    .map(attrs => Product(attrs("id").decodeString(Utf8), attrs.mapValues(_.decodeString(Utf8))))
    .via(es.flow)

val futureDone = graph.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))

futureDone onComplete {
    case Success(_) => println("Done")
    case Failure(e) => println(e)
}
```